# Unable to install correct version of Ansible

Tags: installation, ansible, version, openstack

I installed `ansible==5.0`, however the required was between `2.10-2.11`. Now each time when I tried to remove it, it says `WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.` But when I run command `ansible --version`, the output shows ansible is installed with version `ansible [core 2.12.3]`

I also tried to install required version over it which again successfully installed but when version command again run, it shows that previous version.

```
(kolla-ansible-venv) root@ubuntu:/home/kypo/Desktop# sudo pip3 uninstall --yes ansible
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.
(kolla-ansible-venv) root@ubuntu:/home/kypo/Desktop# apt remove ansible
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ansible' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libfwupdplugin1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
(kolla-ansible-venv) root@ubuntu:/home/kypo/Desktop# ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.3]
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /home/kolla-ansible-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
executable location = /home/kolla-ansible-venv/bin/ansible
python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0]
jinja version = 3.0.3
libyaml = True
(kolla-ansible-venv) root@ubuntu:/home/kypo/Desktop# sudo pip uninstall --yes ansible
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.
(kolla-ansible-venv) root@ubuntu:/home/kypo/Desktop#
```

I am actually want to install openstack by following [this](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/kolla-ansible/ussuri/quickstart.html) link.

Comment: Prior to version 2.11, there was a single `ansible` package having the exact same version as the tools inside. Since version 2.11, this has changed. `ansible` is now a meta package following its own versioning (3.x.x, 4.x.x, 5.x.x) which brings together `ansible-core` which will have the version of the command line tools + collections and other requirements. In your case, it seems `ansible-core` is still installed. This is the pip package you need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

It seems too late for response but I write it here for others.

As it requires an ansible version between `2.10.0` and `2.11.0`,  you should install a version in this interval. As you previously said, you did not install Ansible but should check other Ansible packages to see if there are any. Use this command:

```
pip list | grep ansible
```

then select every package listed and related (maybe the output shows kolla-ansible or other things that are not related to your problem) and use the following command for example:

```
pip uninstall PACKAGES
```

> In the above command you should replace PACKAGES with related packages you found already (e.g. ansible-core).

Then use this command to install the best pip package for your purpose:

```
pip install 'ansible-core<2.11.0'
```

Hope it helps you on your next tries.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete add applications from ansible server or create new VM and install `git`, `python3`, `python3-pip` in server and then clone Kolla-ansible repo and install all dependencies from `requirement.txt` file.
It's the easiest way to install kolla-ansible without dependency.